# WEB API 2 POST, PUT, DELETE Not working

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using ASP.NET WEB API 2 as my data access. The issue i'am having is i'm getting this error when ever i try to use DELETE, PUT OR POST

ERROR: {"$id":"1","Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

However the get methods are working.

Still having the issue even when I've added the below code in my web.config file

```
<authorization>
      <!-- General application authorization -->
      <allow verbs="GET" users="*" />
      <allow verbs="PUT" users="*" />
      <allow verbs="POST" users="*" />
      <allow verbs="DELETE" users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: How are you constructing your requests?

Comment: Hey Yannick, Can you please further clarify of the meaning constructing the requests? Do you mean how i am calling the HTTP methods ?

Comment: Exactly. Are you sure you're explicitly setting the type for each request?

Comment: Please see below.                                                                                                    User Controller [HttpDelete]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var userService = new UserService();

            userService.GetByID(id);

            if (userService == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            userService.DeleteUser(id);
        }

Comment: No, what I mean is, how are you calling the action on your controller? Via JQuery.Ajax or some other means? I'm asking because what I'm assuming you're doing is just hitting the URL, which by default performs a GET. You have to specify the `type` (also called `method`) when constructing your request.

Comment: Ohh, Please see below                                                                                                  function userFactory($http) {

        var urlBase = '/api/api/';
        factory = {};

        factory.DeleteRecord = function (id) {

            return $http.delete(urlBase + 'user/Delete?id=' + id);
        };

        return factory;

    };

Comment: Aah, missed your tag for angularJS :( Hmm, that seems correct from first glance. I'll dig a bit further.

Comment: Thankyou :) I've been researching for our hours. Still could not find a solution why each request is performing GET

Comment: @erkaner, that makes no sense. He's calling .delete() on his context because semantically, that's exactly what he wants to do. To wrap data changing operations into a read context by changing the verb to GET is confusing to say the least.